# Exception when initializing custom RestResource

Tags: jersey-2.0, atg, oracle-commerce

I'm having a problem with a custom RestResource. I want to replace the OOTB UserRestResource with my own implementation. When nucleus starts up I get the following exception:

```
Scan failed to process nucleus rest resource class:class com.test.restresources.UserRestResource 
path:/atg/userprofiling/restresources/UserRestResource
atg.service.jaxrs.RestException: Endpoint annotated method without a http method annotation
```

The class has the following implementation:

```
@RestResource(id = "com.pki.ebusiness.ocs.restresources.userRestResource")
@Path("/users")
@Api(value="/users")
public class UserRestResource extends GenericService {
    private UserRepository mUserRepository;
    private DomainObjectMapper mObjectMapper = DomainObjectMapper.INSTANCE;

    @GET
    @Path("/{userId}")
    @Endpoint(id = "/users/{userId}#GET", isSingular = true, filterId = "users.id-Default")
    @ApiOperation("Retrieve a user for given ID.")
    public RepresentationModel getUser(@PathParam("userId") String pUserId){
        User user = null;
        try {
            user = mUserRepository.getUser(pUserId);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BaseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        UserDto userDto = mObjectMapper.convert(user);

        Builder builder = (new Builder()).state(userDto);
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

While debugging the RestResourceRegistry I found that it is not able to find the Path annotation even though it is there.

Comment: did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

To this `atg/dynamo/service/jaxrs/RestResourceRegistry.properties` add `nucleusProviders+=security/CsrfProtectionFilter`.

This is an issue in OC 11.3.

### UPDATE

In addition to the above add the following entry to `JerseyClassLoaderService.properties`:

```
classpathFiles+=\

       {appModuleResource?moduleID=YourBase.ModuleName&resourceURI=lib/make-jersey-classloader.jar}
```